# Swift/iOS8: Create shared instance for websocket SocketIOCocoa

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to create a shared Instance for a websocket client, using the SocketIOCocoa library found here:
https://github.com/shuoli84/SocketIOCocoa

The library works perfectly fine, when used inside a ViewController to create a new instance of the websocket client - but i somehow fail to set up a shared instance. What I tried:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

public class WebSocketClient:SocketIOSocket {


    public var WebSocket:SocketIOClient!

    func myWebSocketClient() -> SocketIOClient {

        if WebSocket != nil {
            return WebSocket
        } else {
        let uri = "\(CurrentConfiguration.serverURL)/socket.io/"

        var client = SocketIOClient(uri: uri, reconnect: true, timeout:3000)
        client.open()

        return client
        }
    }
```

As I am quite new to the use of protocols/shared instances I dont know if I am on the right track. At least it doesnt work when I want to use it as:
var foo = WebSocketClient.myWebSocketclient()

This is how I would do it in a single VC:

```
func newSocket() {

let uri = "\(CurrentConfiguration.serverURL)/socket.io/"

var client = SocketIOClient(uri: uri, reconnect: true, timeout:3000)
client.open()

var socket = client.socket("myNamespace") //join namespace


socket.event("customEvent", data: websocketRoomData){ (packet) -> Void in
                    }//emit event after join

socket.delegate = self
}


func socketOnEvent(socket: SocketIOSocket, event: String, data: AnyObject?) {

        switch event {
        case "returning from server event":
            println(event)
            let returnData = data as? NSArray

            //do stuff with return data

            doStuff(returnData!)

        default:
            println("Error: unrecognized Websockets Event received!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example.
You can use SocketSingleton.call from any place in your code.

let socket: SocketSingleton = SocketSingleton.call

socket.socketEmit()

```
class SocketSingleton: NSObject {

static let call = SocketSingleton()

let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string:"url")!)

override init() {
    super.init()
    addHandlers()
    socket.connect()
}

func addHandlers() {
    socket.on("message") { data, ack in

    }

    socket.on("reconnect") { data, ack in

    }

    socket.on("error") { data, ack in

    }

}
func socketEmit() {
    let msg = [:]
    var sendJson : NSString = ""
    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(msg, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        let string = NSString(data: json, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        sendJson = string! as NSString
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.description)
    }

    socket.emit("message", sendJson)
}

}
```